# JW Player v4 event listener

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am using version 4 of this player and want to be able to interact with it as it iterates through each piece of media in the playlist. When a playlist is loaded into the player with XML, I want to get the ID from the media that's currently playing then dynamically show the related info to the user.

There is not much documentation on this version and my JavaScript skills are not that great.

Is what I want to do even possible with this version of JW Player? If it is, can someone either point me to an example that would incorporate this functionality or show me how this can be accomplished?

Comment: JW4 is quite old, but we have some old demos on QA, email us about them - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: @EthanLongTail, Thanks Ethan. I've actually found a demo that I was able to work with. I do have another question though regarding the rss namespace. Can I use completely custom tags in my XML? There are other data that I'm pulling from the database and I'd like to display it below your player. Again, I'm on version 4. If not, I may have to use JSON to get it on the page but since your XML gives me 97% of what I need, I thought I'd ask before I start redoing everything. Thanks again for a wonderful player! Kudos my friend.

Comment: @EthanLongTail, Ethan, I should also mention that I've already tried adding the jqplayer namespace to the rss, modifying the tags as well but all I ever get back is `undefined`. Just as JavaScript isn't my bag, neither is XML so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: The jwplayer namespace was only supported in JW5+, not JW4, I believe. We do not support custom tags in xml though.